# Convert excel formula code to programming language

Tags: excel, random

Hi I have this code and I want to translate it to any other programming language such as Python Java ruby 
As you can see this is a raffle game user presses f5
And generates a raffle number such as Aqua 2231 7533 and stores all entries and at the end makes a random selection

This part is generation part

```
=LOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),{1,2,3},{"Aqua","Blue","Red"})&" "&TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0,9999),"0000")&" "&TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0,9999),"0000")
```

And this part is the random selection

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A)))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could decide on EXACTLY what language you will be using. *'any other programming language'* is more than just a little ambiguous and indicates that you really do not know what you actually want let alone show any indication of research or original effort.

Comment: Any programming language that any of you guys know that can translate to I only know excel ,Python do u know Python

Comment: " any indication of research or original effort" <--- any tries you had with python ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of libraries which may be able to help. I don't know if they support the LOOKUP, RANDBETWEEN or TEXT functions specifically but as they are open source libraries there's potential for you, or someone you know, to add that particular functionailty (all of these projects welcome such input).

The libraries for Python that read Excel and generate Python code are;

- [PyCel](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel)
- [Formulas](https://github.com/vinci1it2000/formulas) and [Schedula](https://github.com/vinci1it2000/schedula)
- [xlcaclulator](https://github.com/bradbase/xlcalculator) (This is my project)
- [Koala](https://github.com/vallettea/koala)

In each case these libraries have an "evaluator" which can actually run the generated Python code. Some of these evaluators are integrated with the Excel file reading functionality, in other cases it's separate.

PyCel and Koala2 have the evaluation functionality integrated with the Excel file reading functions. xlcalculator has them in separate objects. Formulas and Schedula have them in separate projects.

It's not easy for them to print out or save "vanilla" Python code due to what needs to happen to evaluate the generated code. The evaluation code needs access to the Python implementation of the Excel formula and, as things are at the moment, all of these projects use their own libraries with their own objects and their own mechanisms to call said objects. xlcalculator has attempted to extract the Python implementations of the Excel formulas to have a library anyone can use but it is also the most recently written so who knows how successful that will become. That library is called xlfunctions.

Providing the above mentioned projects support LOOKUP, RANDBETWEEN and TEXT functions, they will be able to read the function you've written (without the need for Excel to be installed), translate the function into Python code and execute the resulting code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be that hard.. Just :

1. Copy the formula & break it up in notepad++
2. For each function used, read up WORD-BY-WORD its documented documentation.
3. One you understand the data flow/change/list/start/end in the program.. use your mother tongue language, Ink it (the understanding) down. you may draw if it helps..
4. In the programming language of your choice, implement the "mother tongue" algorithm in that language.
5. Test the program with exactly the same input you gave to the original excel formula.. edit if necessary.

Since you didn't share ANY form of tries.. this is the best I have.. which works for me.. sorry if hurts/didn't solve..

Hope someone can improve/edit my answer for the better. (: